# My primality test ignores a condition. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, loops

As a newbie python enthusiast, I find this very annoying:

```
def isPrime(x):
    if x < 0: raise Exception("The number is negative.")
    if x == 0 or x == 1: return False
    if x == 2: return True
    else:
        if x % 2 == 0: return False
        for i in xrange (3, int(math.sqrt(x)), 2): #-------> This doesn't do anything.
            if x % i == 0: return False # Even if I put 3 instead of i, it still prints numbers that are divisible by 3.
    return True

for i in xrange (100):
    if isPrime(i):
        print i
```

I get numbers like 9, 15, 21 - divisible by 3, therefore not primes. What am I missing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You want `xrange (3, int(math.sqrt(x)) + 1, 2)` - remember that `xrange` iterates through all values from its start point, inclusive, to its stop point, exclusive.

More concretely, when `x` is 9, you have `xrange (3, 3, 2)` which does not iterate over anything.

Comment: Nice catch! For the OP's benefit, this is called an [off by one error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error). It's common enough to warrant its own Wikipedia article.